# Scope while initializing static variables

Tags: c++, static

So there is a question I came across

```
int f() {
    return 5;
}

struct A{
    static int sX;
    static int f() {
        return 1;
    }
};

int A::sX = f(); // (1)
```

This complies fine. I wanted to understand why `(1)` ends up having a

```
call    A::f()
```

in its [compiled](https://godbolt.org/z/YesMjxGYh) code. I understand there is some scope rule being invoked here but would like to know the exact rule. I'd expected it to invoke the global `f()`. Why doesn't the (*unqualified*?)name lookup of `f` yield the global function?

P.S. I'd looked up [`ADL`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) but since `f()` doesn't accept any arguments, would `ADL` kick in?

Edit: I think I found the answer to my question. Check this [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#:%7E:text=Definition%20outside%20of%20its%20namespace) under `unqualified name lookup` which states:

> For a name used in the definition of a namespace-member variable
> outside the namespace, lookup proceeds the same way as for a name used
> inside the namespace:
>
> ```
> namespace X {
>     extern int x; // declaration, not definition
>     int n = 1; // found 1st
> };
> int n = 2; // found 2nd.
> int X::x = n; // finds X::n, sets X::x to 1
> ```

Comment: If someone thinks this is a dupe, they should provide a simple answer targetting my specific question and then dupe it, so that I have some context. The other question doesn't answer my question at all and now I'm pretty sure that this question won't be reviewed for re-opening.

Comment: I think that's plain unqualified name lookup, not ADL (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup section "Static data member definition")

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static.data#3

Comment: @Mat, I missed your comment. I updated my answer with my finding. Would you want to provide an answer? I can accept it.